# Grok filter for my log pattern

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, grok

I am experimenting with ELK. I try to input log with the following pattern to logstash

```
14:25:43.324 [http-nio-9090-exec-116] INFO  com.app.MainApp - Request has been detected
```

I have tried the following grok patterns as a filter in logstash.conf

```
match => { “message” => [ “ (?<timestamp>%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) \[%{NOTSPACE:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:Class}\- %{GREEDYDATA:message}“ ]}

match => { “message” => [ “ %{TIME:timestamp} \[%{NOTSPACE:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:Class}\- %{GREEDYDATA:message}“ ]}
```

But when I input log to logstash , I get the following error

```
   [0] "_grokparsefailure"
```

Can someone suggest the correct grok filter for the above log pattern ?

Comment: Your first character in your pattern is a space. Is this intended?

Comment: @Fairy No it is not

Comment: Well then there you have your problem. Getting rid of the space will match both of your patterns correctly.

Comment: @Fairy It's working fine. But the problem which I am facing now is wrt message parsing "message" => [
        [0] "20:19:05.216 [qtp231935802-12] INFO  com.iriiis.app.notes.NoteService - ping called",
        [1] "ping called"
    ]   How do i fix this ?

Comment: Please update the question. It is quite difficult to read it from comments.

Comment: @Fairy : I am facing another issue. Can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122250/grok-parse-error-while-parsing-multiple-line-messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parse failure got fixed after removing the starting space. So the working logstash.conf after removing the space is like below

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["./debug.log"]
    codec => multiline {
      # Grok pattern names are valid! :)
      pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
      negate => true
      what => previous
    }
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{NOTSPACE:uid}\] \[%{NOTSPACE:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:class}\-%{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}


output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```